# string operation like binary AND

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am trying to make a lightweight recommendation engine. I've pondered for hours on end on how to accomplish this and I think I might be on to something but I need a 3rd person view on the matter. Here goes:

- Let's say I have 100,000 possible distinct items and each user can add any number of those into his `inventory`.
- A user can add into his `wishlist` any of those 100,000 items as well.
- Let's say a user adds 100 items into his wishlist, I want to find all other users who have these items in their inventory. Then rank them accordingly to who has the most items to offer.

The first way I thought of solving this is through simple MySQL joins. I tried firing up some test data and with just 50,000 users each having their own inventory/wishlist the query seems very slow (~10s), what more with pagination? So I considered maybe having the data aggregation on a different software, port the data to another software (or table) to page through them.

I've tried a couple of things as well (Redis LUA loop, MongoDB MapReduce) but they all resulted in the same speed. What I want to do is to be able to do this real time, and I can't help but wonder if that's even possible, and that I just haven't found the right solution yet. Or that maybe I'm just over complicating things. My latest exploration led me to bit AND operations since I heard they're pretty fast, but I seem to have hit a wall on that too.

- My idea is for each user to have a string containing 100,000 characters containing 1s and 0s where each character/bit will represent an item in the user's inventory.
- Each user will have another string for their wishlist which will be used as the query to the database.

What would be ideal is to loop through each user, do an AND operation with the wishlist vs the inventory and count the number of bits in the result. Once the loop is done then transfer the result to a different table where you can page through.

I know 100,000-bit binary is a bit silly. Is it even possible to do binary operations on such a thing? Do you think there are other solutions that I am over-looking? One thing I haven't looked at yet is bloom filters to eliminate the users who do not have a single item on a user's wishlist, that will narrow down the number of users to search through. I am open to any suggestions.

Edit:

Here's what I was doing in MySQL that I wanted to improve upon:

```
SELECT
user_id, SUM(card_qty) qty
FROM (
    SELECT
    cc.user_id, card_info_id, LEAST(c.card_qty, cc.card_qty) card_qty
    FROM mb_decks d
    JOIN mb_decks_cards c USING (deck_id)
    JOIN mb_collection_cards cc USING (card_info_id)
    WHERE d.deck_id = 1
    AND cc.user_id <> d.deck_user_id
) t1
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY qty DESC;
# Showing rows 0 - 24 (33002 total, Query took 4.2979 sec)
```

Please download the schema and test data [here](http://files.ramon.ph/mb.tar.gz).

Comment: Consider postgresql and it's smlar extension, which was designed for collaborative filtering.

Answer (score 0):

1. What does your query and tables look like? This problem shouldn't be too hard for myself with proper indexing.
2. If you're really set on going outside of mysql, elasticsearch is BUILT for this kind of quick querying.

Comment: Please see my edit for the table schema/data and query. I've read about elasticsearch use cases and they said it's bad for inventory type queries.